# Trying to get this SVG to cover the button?

Tags: javascript, svg

I made this SVG, now I'm trying to get it to cover the button, how do I do this?

As you can see in the code it's hanging off the button, How do I have it cover the button?

**Code:**

https://jsfiddle.net/ztmvxnft/2/

**SVG:**

```
<svg width="266" height="266" viewBox="0 0 266 266">
  <line x1="264" y1="1" x2="0" y2="1" style="stroke: #0059dd; stroke-width: 3;" />
  <line x1="265" y1="265" x2="265" y2="0" style="stroke: #0059dd;stroke-width: 3; " />
  <line x1="100%" y1="265" x2="0" y2="265" style="stroke: #0059dd ; stroke-width: 3;" />
  <line x1="1" y1="100%" x2="1" y2="0" style="stroke:#0059dd;stroke-width: 3; " />
  <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="100%" y2="100%" style="stroke:#0059dd; stroke-width:3" />
  <line x1="0" y1="100%" x2="100%" y2="0" style="stroke:#0059dd; stroke-width:3" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Could you post your code as text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The user-agent stylesheet likely has (and in the case of Chrome definitely has) padding inside buttons. If you add `padding:0` to your styling of the button, the SVG fits correctly.

**Edit:** With that change, you may still see that the SVG does not quite fit, depending on the browser. If so, that is because the "266px" size of the button includes the border of the button. If you want the SVG to fit entirely within the button, you can change the `box-sizing` to `content-box` as in the JSfiddle below, but keep in mind that it means your button will be a little larger than 266px. Alternately, you can set the `border-width` to `0` (or the `border` to `none`) to eliminate the border entirely at which point the button will be exactly 266px.

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yupwrLxj/)